# Cannot get jQuery validation to work with MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

I have a custom regex method:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "dateRegex",
       function(value, element, regexp) {
         var re = new RegExp(regexp);
         return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
       },
       "Date must be in the format MM/DD/YYYY"
 );
```

I've got jQuery validation on a date field that looks like this:

```
rules:
      date:
        {
        required: true,
        dateRegex: '^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- //.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- //.](19|20)\d\d$',
        maxlength: 10
        }
      }
messages: {
    lossDate: {
    required: "Unable to proceed, search field is empty"
    }   
}
```

When I enter a valid date, for example 08/06/2013, "Date must be in the format MM/DD/YYYY" is displayed.  Does anyone see a mistake in my regex, or is the problem outside of that?

The test data passes here:  http://regexpal.com/

Also, I have the following working in my app:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
       var re = new RegExp(regexp);
       return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Invalid number of characters entered."
);

number: 
      {
    required: true,
    regex: '^(.{7}|.{9}|.{11}|.{12}|.{15})$' 
      },...
```

Comment: Looks like you need to precede the values with zeros.  `08/06/2013`

Comment: @Sparky, Thanks for pointing that out.  That was a typo.  The validation still returns false with the zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that plugin doesn't want strings for regexes. Instead of a string literal, put a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression):

```
…,
dateRegex: /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$/,
…
```

You also can simplify the function then:

```
function(value, element, regexp) {
    return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
}
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  I have a different version of the same thing that works.  I've added it to my question.

Comment: With your string, the backslashes in `"\d"` do not escape anything. The `new RegExp` would match a literal `d` then. Try to input `08/06/20dd`

Comment: I apologize, you were correct about the plugin not taking a string.  I suppose that's because I was passing a Date type.  Do you agree?

Comment: A [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)? No. With the `RegExp` constructor as you had it, you needed to pass `'^ … [- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$'` (a real backslash before the `d`)